# How does the heap allocate memory on windows?

Tags: c, windows, memory-management

I have been trying to learn more about how memory allocation works on windows and from what I found it seems malloc calls HeapAlloc underneath the hood. What I'm curious about is how HeapAlloc works.

1. Does it call VirtualAlloc? If so how does it resize the memory allocated with it when the heap is full? From what I've seen there is no such thing as VirtualReAlloc.
2. Are there any opensource allocators for windows that don't call malloc or HeapAlloc underneath the hood?

Comment: Windows isn't open source, so the only option would be to use their provided API.

Comment: Clearly you cannot use VirtualReAlloc because that would move the memory, invalidating all existing heap allocation pointers. But there's no requirement that heap memory be contiguous. ReactOS has [its own implementation of HeapAlloc](https://doxygen.reactos.org/df/d0a/heapalloc_8c_source.html) you can look at.

Comment: It uses VirtualAlloc. It doesn't resize memory.

Comment: The Visual Studio CRT library (where `malloc` is implemented) is available in source-form if you install Visual Studio. You can always look at that. And there are many many "malloc" replacements implementations for all kind of platforms, all open-source in one way or another.